# Is there a way for users of my website to invite their friends via LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using the Facebook and LinkedIn API to allow users of my website to link their social network account with their website account, and I want to give them an opportunity to invite their friends from social networks to my site.
On the Refer-A-Friend page, I want to include Invite via Facebook and LinkedIn buttons which will send a request to those friends from that service.
In Facebook API I can do that with `fb:request-form` FBML tag. 
The only possibility, I saw in LinkedIn Invitation API - is to add website users to your linkedin network but not the opposite.
So, Is there a way for users of my website to invite their LinkedIn friends?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, LinkedIn doesn't provide connection's email but still  you invite them through API but the message will go into linkedIn site message box.

Try with linkedIn API how to import connection and send them message. As i have already worked on that way and it's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Linkedin doesn't provide connection's email address  , therefor you cannot invite friend via linkedin . I guess you had already google a lot about it and found that term.

My statement is based on following reference .

https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/export-contacts-email-using-c-or-java 
http://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-the-LinkedIn-API-provide-email-addresses